# Retry client request after external condition is met

Tags: ktor, ktor-client

I want to retry a KTor client request after an external condition is met (such as showing a UI to  re-request authorization from the user) when they receive a certain HTTP status code.

`HttpRequestRetry` is time based and not a great fit for suspending a request while the user executes the external action.

The `Auth` plugin does not have a concept of needing to redo an authorization due to expiration time has been reached.

Looking into how the `Auth` and `HttpRequestRetry` work, they both access an internal function
`takeFromWithExecutionContext` to make the sub-request and tie them back to the original coroutine scope.

Is there another way to make a custom retry system that does not rely on internal methods?

Comment: Could you just suspend execution when an external condition is met?

Comment: That's what I thought, but unsure what the significance of changing of the Job in the executionContext (internal setter) in this block and not doing that would cause issues on the retried request: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/b3b52089a45da58ca2d0ada0ee97806aea426ecc/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/plugins/HttpRequestRetry.kt#L328-L333

Comment: Also, can you just make a new request with an HTTP client when an external condition is met? The `Auth` and `HttpRequestRetry` plugins serve a specific purpose so I don't think they are a good fit for your problem.